# VBA Code runs in excel 2013 but not in 2010

Tags: vba, excel

The following code I've written using excel 2013 works on excel 2013, but when trying it on my company's 2010 version of excel it produces an error when I click Cancel button on inputbox dialog box and stops at the line of code:

```
EntryDate = CDate(InputBox("Insert Date", "Insert Date", vbOKCancel))
```

says: type Mismatch and the number is: Run-time error'13':

Why?

```
    Sub InsertNewEntry()
'
' InsertNewEntry Macro
' To Insert New Entry for exchange rates
'

Dim LastRow As Integer, EntryDate As Date
Dim EURtoUSD As Double, JODtoUSD As Double, ILStoUSD As Double

' determine the number of the last row entered
LastRow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Exchange Rates Template").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

'determine if last date is last day of the year
   If Cells(LastRow, 2) = #12/31/2014# Then
    MsgBox "You are not allowed to insert a date above " & "31/12/ " & Cells(4, 1).Value
    Exit Sub
   Else
    Cells(LastRow, 4).Select
    Selection.ListObject.ListRows.Add AlwaysInsert:=False
    Cells(LastRow, 8).Select
    Selection.ListObject.ListRows.Add AlwaysInsert:=False
    Cells(LastRow, 12).Select
    Selection.ListObject.ListRows.Add AlwaysInsert:=False
    Cells(LastRow + 1, 2).Select
    EntryDate = CDate(InputBox("Insert Date", "Insert Date", vbOKCancel))
      If EntryDate <> "" Then
       Cells(LastRow + 1, 2) = EntryDate
       Cells(LastRow + 1, 3) = "EUR to USD"
       Cells(LastRow + 1, 6) = EntryDate
       Cells(LastRow + 1, 7) = "JOD to USD"
       Cells(LastRow + 1, 10) = EntryDate
       Cells(LastRow + 1, 11) = "ILS to USD"
      Else
       Cells(LastRow + 1, 2).Select
       Selection.ListObject.ListRows(LastRow - 3).Delete
       Cells(LastRow + 1, 6).Select
       Selection.ListObject.ListRows(LastRow - 3).Delete
       Cells(LastRow + 1, 10).Select
       Selection.ListObject.ListRows(LastRow - 3).Delete
       Exit Sub

      End If
   End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change `EntryDate As Date` to `EntryDate As Variant`

and also change the line,

```
EntryDate = CDate(InputBox("Insert Date", "Insert Date", vbOKCancel))` to
```

to

```
EntryDate = InputBox("Insert Date", "Insert Date", vbOKCancel)
```

and after that line

Add this line

```
If EntryDate = False Then Exit Sub
```

After this line, you may write

```
EntryDate  = Cdate(EntryDate)
```

And the reason is simple because `Cdate(False)` will give you `00:00:00` and `Cdate(True)` will give you `29/12/1899`

**Followup from comments**

Is this what you are trying?

```
Dim EntryDate As Variant

EntryDate = InputBox("Insert Date", "Insert Date", vbOKCancel)

If EntryDate = False Then Exit Sub

If EntryDate <> "" Then
    EntryDate = CDate(EntryDate)
    Cells(LastRow + 1, 2).Value = EntryDate
    Cells(LastRow + 1, 3).Value = "EUR to USD"
    Cells(LastRow + 1, 6).Value = EntryDate
    Cells(LastRow + 1, 7).Value = "JOD to USD"
    Cells(LastRow + 1, 10).Value = EntryDate
    Cells(LastRow + 1, 11).Value = "ILS to USD"
Else
    Cells(LastRow + 1, 2).ListObject.ListRows(LastRow - 3).Delete
    Cells(LastRow + 1, 6).ListObject.ListRows(LastRow - 3).Delete
    Cells(LastRow + 1, 10).ListObject.ListRows(LastRow - 3).Delete
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Comment: ok what should I do with the else statement? it will be alone without and if statement?

Comment: One moment updating my post

Comment: +1 quick answer! I haven't even had time to read the question:)

Comment: @SiddharthRout Yes this is what I am trying to do, and Cdate here because I want the application to insert the date value as a date format so Filtering will be supported

Comment: @MohammadTaha: Yeah I understood that so I removed that comment :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout by the way,, nice shortening for the last three lines :)

Comment: @MohammadTaha: [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select) is my mantra :p

Comment: @SiddharthRout the type mismatch error still triggers when I click cancel

Comment: @SiddharthRout this one EntryDate = CDate(EntryDate)

Comment: @MohammadTaha: See my previous comment ;)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45202/discussion-between-siddharth-rout-and-mohammad-taha)